# Modifying a CSV header to match values

Tags: python, parsing, csv, pandas

I'm trying to read a csv file into a pandas dataframe in Python, but there is an extra comma used in one column because it has a range

I have a comma delimited csv with 13 columns of data, but one of the columns is a range of values, and uses an extra comma. The header looks like:

```
"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M"
```

but the values in each row of data look like:

```
"A",B,B,"C","D","E","F","G","H",I,"J",K,L,M
```

I'm trying to read this into a Pandas dataframe in Python, but with the inconsistency it will treat the tuple as two columns. How would I go about changing the csv so that it is easier to parse?

Comment: You mean B has values on a range like 0,10?

Comment: Yes - sorry, I should have specified that the letters represented variables, and the data looks something like "11111", 2222, 2222, "333",...; some of the columns have a quotation mark but some do not, and the 2nd variable has an extra comma because it's a range.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
def fixed_lines(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader)       # skip header(optional)
        for row in reader:
            yield row[:1] + [row[1] + ',' + row[2]] + row[3:]

pd.DataFrame(fixed_lines('filename.csv'))
```